# How do you get responseText from jQuery.getJSON method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to read in a JSON file from my directory using the jQuery.getJSON method and it returns the object shown in the picture. I want to get the responseText from the object but cannot figure out how.

```
var jsonData = jQuery.getJSON('relationalData.json');
```

Ive tried to use the following to extract the responseText but they all failed.

```
var response = jsonData.responseText;
var response = jsonData['responseText'];
```

[image: This is the object I get once I use the jQuery.getJSON on my json file.]

I also tried using without any luck, as the method doesn't even get called with a json file. It worked when I used an xml though.

```
$.get(filename, function(data){
   var responseText = data;
});
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the docs where it shows how to do it and provides examples? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: `$.getJSON(filename, function(data){
   var responseText = data;
});` will work

Comment: $.get likely failing due to improper content type header from server, adding dataType argument ( as shown in docs) would likely make it work if json is valid

Comment: Thank you charlietfi! I just put the json file in a validator and there was one off piece to it. I fixed the error in the file and the $.get works now. @charlietfl

Comment: @Chris _"I fixed the error in the file and the $.get works now."_ Is Question resolved ?

Comment: @guest271314 yes, what should i mark as correct answer?

Comment: @guest271314 the correct answer was in the comment to my question, there was no actual answer that had it.

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution to guest271314 but, maybe, still instructive for someone ...

```js
$.getJSON('http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/artist.json?q=foo')
 .done(function(obj,status,xhdr){$('#out').append(xhdr.responseText);});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out"><div>
```

The important part is to look for the `.responseText` property in the `xhdr` object, which can be accessed though the third parameter of the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question which has been longed asked, but for future visitors where is my solution:

$.getJSON method fetches data from a server using HTTP GET request, the response on successful call returns in a responseText property as you see in your console.

Therefore to get the data of the responseText you have to use the JSON.parse() method to retrieve data to javaSrcipt object like this:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonCall.responseText);
```

But $.getJSON() method is asynchronous so this must be done inside the callback function if not the response may not exist.

Final solution:

```
var jsonCall = $.getJSON('URL',function(){
   var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonCall.responseText);
   console.log(jsonData);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try utilizing [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then) , substituting `responseJSON` for `responseText`

```js
var jsonData = jQuery.getJSON("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/23e61e522a14d45a35e1/raw/a5ac6cffdc1ffab39f9db425844721b528751654/a.json");

jsonData.then(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  alert(jqxhr.responseJSON)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$.ajax` returns a promise and is asynchronous

Comment: @charlietfl _"$.ajax returns a promise"_ `jQuery.ajax` returns a _jQuery promise object_ ? , not only value or reason that es6 promise would ?

Comment: not sure what you are asking but the data needs to be accessed in callback